# Calculation of probability of selling a Poisson number of products

Tags: self-study, poisson-distribution

You sell 10 product on average every day. The model is based on a Poisson distribution.
To be enable to cover the indirect cost, the manager needs to sell 8 products per day.

Two questions:

> 1. What is the probability to sell between 0 - 5 products in a day?
> 2. What is the probability to have at least 6 products in a single day?

Comment: Legato, if you read the tag wiki on [self study](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) you will see that you have some responsibilities under that tag before we are supposed to give answers in the form of hints. What have you tried already? Did you get as far as writing down the Poisson probability function? How would you work out the probability of selling exactly 5 products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a random variable $X \sim \textrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, the probability of seeing a value of $k$ is:
$$
P_k = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^k}{k!}
$$
So the probability of selling less than or equal to $5$ products in a given day, where the long-term average is $8$ is:
$$
P_{0\ldots5}=\sum_{i=0}^5\frac{e^{-8} \lambda^i}{i!}
$$

The probability of at least $6$ is everything other than $0$ to $5$ or $(1-P_{0\ldots5})$ for which you were asked in the first part.

Comment: The parameter in the question wasn't eight but ten ... but on the other hand, in my book that's a good thing to change, since it doesn't go as close to just giving the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the probabilities manually or you can do it with R. The code for the cumulative distr. of Poisson is ppois(k,m), k being the limit $P(X\leq k) $ and m the parameter of the distribution.